# How to copy to clipboard from browser using python 3.10.4 and Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: clipboard, python-3.10, pyperclip, ubuntu-22.04

I have the following code that is automating a process in the browser.
At the line `pt.click(clicks=3)` I can get the text selected in the input box (Chrome). At the line `pc.copy()` I should copy this text and send it to the variable `self.message` to be processed. This step is not working.
There are a lot of documents and tutorials on how to do that on Windows and Mac, not in Ubuntu, specially in Ubuntu 22.04.

I am using OS `Ubuntu 22.04` and `Python 3.10.4`.

What am I missing?

```
from turtle import right
import cv2 as cv
from time import sleep
# Waiting time
print('Waiting 2s')
sleep(2)

import pyautogui as pt
import paperclip as pc
from tkinter import ttk

....

def nav_message(self):
    try:
        clipPicCenter = pt.locateCenterOnScreen('./clip_pic.png', confidence=0.7)
        # print('LocateCenter clip_pic', clipPicCenter)
        pt.moveTo(clipPicCenter[0]+48, clipPicCenter[1]-60, duration=self.speed) 

        pt.click(clicks=3)
        sleep(.9)

        self.message = pc.copy() //Out PUT - Pyperclip do not have the method copy()
        print(self.message)

        # pt.click(button='right', clicks=1)
        # pos = pt.position()
        # pt.moveTo(pos[0]+20, pos[1]-300, duration=self.speed)
        # txt = pt.click()
        # print(txt)
        # self.nav_input_box()
        # pt.write(txt)
        # txt = pt.hotkey("ctrl", "c") # copy the text (simulating key strokes)
        # pt.click(button=right)
        

    except Exception as e:
        print ('Exception (nav_green_dot): ', e)
```

Comment: line 9 imports the `paperclip` module (https://pypi.org/project/paperclip/). Is that just a typo in your question or is it in your code?

Comment: This is what I am using `import paperclip as pc`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to copy something to your clipboard

```
 import pyperclip
 s1 = "Hello world"
 pyperclip.copy(s1)
 s2 = pyperclip.paste()
 print(s2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 9 you import `paperclip` as `pc`. You need to import `pyperclip` as `pc` (Note that it starts with `py` and not `pa`). The 2 are spelled similar, but your code imports the [paperclip](https://pypi.org/project/paperclip/) library for Django instead of the [pyperclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/) library for managing the clipboard. Heres a codeblock with your fixed imports:

```
from turtle import right
import cv2 as cv
from time import sleep
# Waiting time
print('Waiting 2s')
sleep(2)

import pyautogui as pt
# this used to be "paperclip"
# "pyperclip" is what you need to import
import pyperclip as pc
from tkinter import ttk
```